# Debian Failed to create signal handling thread: 11

Tags: debian, wifi

When I try to connect to Wi-Fi, this failure appears. Why am I getting this error?

I am using this command line:

```
root@LicheePi:/# nmcli dev wifi connect "Galaxy" password "xxxxx"
Failed to create signal handling thread: 11root@LicheePi:/#
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a known bug in your very old version of nmcli: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1368353.

That was six-and-a-half years ago!

Are you still using a debian Jessie? You probably need to update your whole distro to fix that, as modern nmcli will need a more modern NetworkManager, which is part of a more modern systemd.

Comment: To update the Debian version to a higher version than Jessie, do I need to create a new image file?  @MarcusMüller

Comment: I have no idea about your system, how am I supposed to be able to answer that? (you're serious about Jessie?!)

Comment: I am using the Lichee Pi Zero development board with the Debian Jessie image. @MarcusMüller

Comment: The Debian Jessie version was a default image file provided by the manufacturer. That's why I'm using this @MarcusMüller

Comment: yeah, that won't do. I have no knowledge of that board, but there's no immediate reason you shouldn't be able to update the debian "from within" any less than you could update any other Jessie. It might be better to create a new image based of a more modern debian, but I don't know how easy the vendor SDK makes that for you, so I really can't be of help.